# Log4j log filtering

Tags: xml, logging, log4j

Following is the structure of my `log4j.xml`:

```
<appender name="logfile" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="somelog.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-a" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t]: %c{1} (%X{RequestId}) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="exceptionServiceSoap"
    class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="somelog1.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-a" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t]: %c{1} (%X{RequestId}) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.codehaus.xfire" additivity="true">
            <level value="INFO" />
            <appender-ref ref="exceptionServiceSoap"/>
</logger>

<category name="org">
    <priority value="WARN" />
</category>

<category name="org.hibernate.SQL">
    <priority value="ERROR" />
</category> 

<category name="com">
    <priority value="WARN" />
</category>

<category name="httpclient">
    <priority value="WARN" />
</category>     

<root>
    <appender-ref ref="logfile" />
</root>
```

I want logs generated inside package "`org.codehaus.xfire`" to use appender "`exceptionServiceSoap`" and for all other purposes appender "`logfile`" should be used but with above setup logs of "`org.codehaus.xfire`" are going inside both the appenders. How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but you can try this:

```
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.codehaus.xfire" level="all" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="exceptionServiceSoap"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="all">
        <AppenderRef ref="logfile"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Also your appends should be inside the tag: `<Appenders>...</Appenders>`